# How to connect PostgreSQL from osm2pgrouting

Tags: postgis, osm2pgrouting, osgeo

I am using OSGeo Live. It is an Ubuntu system. I installed it in my PC. I was following one pgRouting workshop.

https://workshop.pgrouting.org/index.html

In one step, I needed to connect osm2pgrouting with postgis to import data. But, the commands are not working. It is showing following connection fail error. I did not change anything. All the passwords are as default.

```
$ osm2pgrouting -file "data/sampledata.osm" \
>                           -conf "/usr/share/osm2pgrouting/mapconfig.xml" \
>                           -dbname routing \
>                           -user postgres \
>                           -clean
host=127.0.0.1 user=postgres dbname=routing port=5432
connection failed
$
```

I tried to fix it. I edited **/etc/postgresql/8.4/main/pg_hba.conf**, and change the postgres connection method to **trust** from **indent**. But, it does not work. The result is same, as before.

```
# Database administrative login by UNIX sockets
# indent
local   all         postgres                          trust
```

Answer (score 1):

Which OS are you on.

local means none ip connection, socket connection. That said you may want to add the below since you are connection by ip.

```
host     all     all     127.0.0.1/32    trust
```

For ipv6 connection you would need:

```
host     all     all     ::1/128     trust
```

(windows 7 for example usually tries to make an ipv6 connection when you put localhost or 127.0.0.1.

Also don't forget you need to do a config reload for settings to take effect

```
pg_ctl reload
```

or if you can't find that just restart your postgresql service.